# What is the meaning of "There’s definitely a ‘if it ain’t broke, don’t fix it’ kind of thing, which is where, listen, we’ve never known what to do…"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> Recently, Ed Sheeran apparently asked The 1975 to open for him on tour. Matty Healy went ahead and turned down that offer, despite how massive it was financially. Now, he’s explained why.
>
> In a new New Yorker interview, Healy said:
>
> “It’s difficult to be big and say — genuinely — that I have zero commercial ambition. **There’s definitely a ‘if it ain’t broke, don’t fix it’ kind of thing, which is where, listen, we’ve never known what to do and we’ve never tried to do anything.** So the second we stop doing that, we’ll probably f*ck up. I tend to say no to stuff for money. I don’t know how you can write this up without it being rude or inappropriate, but I just got offered a four-month tour next year of stadiums with the biggest singer-songwriter in the world that would’ve made me money that I’ve never even seen or heard of in my life.”

I’d like to understand the sentence in bold above from this article.
Source: [Ed Sheeran Made A Huge Offer To The 1975 To Open For Him And Matty Healy Said No: ‘It’s Not Worth It’](https://uproxx.com/indie/matty-healy-no-1975-opening-ed-sheeran/)

**There’s definitely a ‘if it ain’t broke, don’t fix it’ kind of thing**

Does this mean that they think things are working well, so we shouldn’t change anything?

**which is where, listen, we’ve never known what to do and we’ve never tried to do anything.**

Does this mean that they’ve never known how to be a big band and they’ve never tried to do anything to become a big band?
(For context, they are actually a big band.)

Comment: The quotation is an incoherent mess. I doubt it means anything. If they “never tried to do anything,” how can they “stop doing it”? It is impossible to “fuck up” doing nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the interpretation. I didn’t expect it’d be difficult for even native speakers to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the most clearly phrased sentence ever, but I think Healy was probably speaking [off the cuff](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/off-the-cuff) and informally.  I think your interpretation is mostly correct, though.

> There’s definitely a ‘if it ain’t broke, don’t fix it’ kind of thing

Firstly, are you familiar with the saying ["if it ain't broke, don't fix it"?](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/if%20it%20ain%27t%20broke%2C%20don%27t%20fix%20it)  By "kind of thing", I suspect Healy means "kind of attitude that Healy and the band have", because the conversation is about Healy's opinion on why accepting Sheeran's offer would have been wrong.  I would paraphrase this as "We have an attitude that we should not change something that is working for us."

> which is where, listen, we’ve never known what to do and we’ve never tried to do anything

Here, Healy is explaining the band's attitude in more detail.  His description is probably [self-deprecating](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-deprecating), but I would interpret it as "We do not know how to be a hugely successful band and have never consciously tried to be a hugely successful band", because the context is that he is talking about going on a tour that would have made them lots of money and put them in front of huge audiences.

So, all together, I would interpret it as meaning, "We have never tried to be a hugely successful and popular band and don't really know how to try.  But what we are doing now is working for us, so we don't want to change it."

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation. It helps me to understand this part really well.